# Confusion about Change in Integration Variable

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, coordinate-systems, integration

I'm working through example 3.2 of Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics and have come across a change in integration variables that I just can't seem to get. The example has two different change distributions related by $ \rho_b(\lambda \mathbf{r}) = \rho_a(\mathbf{r})$ and asks for the relationship between the electric potentials. 
According to the book,
$$ \int d^3 r'= \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \int d^3 (\lambda r').  $$
When I try to work through the Jacobian, I get
$$ d^3 r' = \begin{vmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\lambda} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
d^3(\lambda r')  = \frac{1}{\lambda} d^3(\lambda r'),$$
where I'm assuming changing from $ r'$ to $ \lambda r'$ is like going from $\vec{x}$ to $\vec{y}$ where 
$$ y_1 = \lambda x_1, \hskip{1cm} y_2 = x_2\hskip{0.5cm} \text{and} \hskip{0.5cm} y_3 = x_3 .  $$
What am I missing here?

Comment: The change $\mathbf{r}\rightarrow\lambda\mathbf{r}$ means that you should make the change $x\rightarrow\lambda x$, $y\rightarrow\lambda y$ and $z\rightarrow\lambda z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$
\boldsymbol r = \begin{vmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z \\
    \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
    r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
    r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
    r \cos \theta \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$
the associated volume element is
$$
d^3 \boldsymbol r = \begin{vmatrix}
    r \sin \theta \cos \phi & r \cos \theta \cos \phi & - r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
    r \sin \theta \sin \phi & r \cos \theta \sin \phi & r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
    r \cos \theta & - r \sin \theta & 0 \\
    \end{vmatrix} dr d \theta d \phi = r^2 \sin \theta dr d \theta d \phi
$$
Similarly, if
$$
\lambda \boldsymbol r = \begin{vmatrix}
    \lambda x \\
    \lambda y \\
    \lambda z \\
    \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
    \lambda r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
    \lambda r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
    \lambda r \cos \theta \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$
the associated volume element is
$$
d^3 ( \lambda \boldsymbol r ) = \begin{vmatrix}
    \lambda r \sin \theta \cos \phi & \lambda r \cos \theta \cos \phi & - \lambda r \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
    \lambda r \sin \theta \sin \phi & \lambda r \cos \theta \sin \phi & \lambda r \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
    \lambda r \cos \theta & - \lambda r \sin \theta & 0 \\
    \end{vmatrix} dr d \theta d \phi = ( \lambda r)^2 \sin \theta  dr d \theta d \phi = \lambda^2 ( r^2 \sin \theta  dr d \theta d \phi )
$$
So, comparing the two expressions above for $d^3 \boldsymbol r$ and 
$d^3 ( \lambda \boldsymbol r )$, you get
$$
d^3 ( \lambda \boldsymbol r ) = \lambda^2 d^3 \boldsymbol r
$$
or
$$
d^3 r = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} d^3 ( \lambda \boldsymbol r )
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget pieces of the integral that gives the potential :

${{d}^{3}}(\lambda \overrightarrow{r'})={{\lambda }^{3}}{{d}^{3}}(\overrightarrow{r'})$ as indicated in the comment.

But : $\int{{{d}^{3}}(\overrightarrow{r'})\frac{\rho (\lambda \overrightarrow{r'})}{\left| \overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r'} \right|}}=\frac{1}{{{\lambda }^{2}}}\int{{{d}^{3}}(\lambda \overrightarrow{r'})\frac{\rho (\lambda \overrightarrow{r'})}{\left| \lambda \overrightarrow{r}-\lambda \overrightarrow{r'} \right|}}$